# How can I add items to a list without innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an empty ul in html and everytime I add or remove a color I call ShowColors which adds li items via JavaScript using .innerHTML. How can I optimize this code without using .innerHTML?

```js
const colorList = document.querySelector(".all-colors");

function ShowColors() {
    colorList.innerHTML = savedColorsArray.map(color => `
        <li class="color">
            <span class="rect" data-color="${color}" style="background: ${color};"></span>
        </li>`).join("");
};
```

```html
<ul class="all-colors"></ul>
```

I tried .insertAdjacentHTML but I would have to change how the code works to save each element so I can remove it later and also probably have to save it to localStorage so it's persistent.

```js
savedColorsArray.forEach(color => {
    colorList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li class="color">
    <span class="rect" data-color="${color}" style="background: ${color};"></span>
</li>`);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of storing those colors in innerHTML, you need to show them?

Comment: In my experience, `.innerHTML` is extremely fast.

Comment: So what is the issue with inerHTML?

Comment: Yes, I show them and also add an eventListener to each color. I was told that .innerHTML is slow and has security issues (XSS injections). My app is simple, I am just curious if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: It does not have XSS if you control the code. You can use event delegation to stop having to add event listeners.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: `innerHTML` _can_ have a performance hit if, for example, you're concatenating html to it within a loop: `element.innerHTML += html`. But you're creating a HTML string using `map` and `join` and only _then_ assigning that to `innerHTML`. And that is fine. I see no reason to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modern approach could be a reactive solution with `Proxy`:
you just modify an array of colors and the list is updated automatically.
You just iterate the color array and try to reuse existing `<li>`. If there's a `<li>` with the same index as a color, update it with `dataset.color = color` and `style.background = color`. Otherwise create an `<li>` with `innerHTML` like you did. The reusing of DOM elements seems like optimization like you requested.

[image]

```js
const colorList = document.querySelector(".all-colors");

const deleteItem = item => 
savedColorsArray.splice([...colorList.children].indexOf(item.closest('.color')), 1);

let updatePromise;

let updateCount = 0;

const savedColorsArray = new Proxy([], {
  set(target, prop, val){
    // postpone in a microtask  
    updatePromise ??= Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      updatePromise = null;
      const log = document.createElement('div');
      log.textContent = `updated ${++updateCount}`;
      document.querySelector('.log').appendChild(log);
      let idx = 0;
      const $children = [...colorList.children];
      for(const color of target){
        let $item = $children[idx++];
        if(!$item){
          const div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = `<li class="color">
            <span  class="rect" data-color="${color}" style="background: ${color};"><b onclick="deleteItem(this)">✕</b></span>
        </li>`;
          colorList.appendChild(div.children[0]);
        }else{
          const $span = $item.querySelector('span');
          $span.dataset.color = color;
          $span.style.background = color;
        }

      }
      // clear unused items
      while(idx < $children.length){
        $children[idx++].remove();
      }
    });
  
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, val);
  }
});

savedColorsArray.push(...'red orange yellow lime green blue'.split(' '));
```

```css
.color span{
  display:block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius:4px;
  transition: background .5s;
  position:relative;
}
.all-colors{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
b{
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
  top:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.color{
  padding: 5px;
  display:block;
  list-style:none;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  gap:30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="all-colors"></ul>
<div>
  <input>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('input').value.match(/\w+/g)?.forEach(color => savedColorsArray.unshift(color))">Add color</button>
</div>
<div class="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` should be avoided whenever possible because calling it invokes the HTML parser, which rebuilds the DOM with the new content, so there are performance implications to using it.

While the DOM is being rebuilt with new content, it's very easy to wipe out previously added event handlers, so there is an opportunity to introduce bugs.

It is well known that using `.innerHTML` can potentially open up a security vulnerability in code as well, when the string that is passed to it is not 100% within the control of the developer.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security
> review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being
> rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and
> submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it may be rejected in the
> review process. Please see Safely inserting external content into a
> page for alternative methods.

So, the moral of the story is, only use `.innerHTML` when you have no other choice. Fortunately, there often are other choices, the first among them being to create new DOM elements, configure them, and then attach them to the DOM.

Here's how that is done:

```js
const colorList = document.querySelector(".all-colors");

function ShowColors() {
  // Create a new DOM elements
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const span = document.createElement("span");  
  
  // Configure the elements via DOM properties
  li.classList.add("color");
  span.classList.add("rect");
  span.style.backgroundColor = color;
  span.dataset.dataColor = color:
  
  // Append the new DOM element to the appropriate parent elements
  li.appendChild(span);
  colorList.appendChild(li);
};
```

Comment: So where is the loop OP had? Where are you emptying the UL?

Comment: @epascarello I am showing an example of how to create, configure, and append a new element to the DOM. The OP can incorporate this into their particular solution however they need to.